# Why print num is always zero in emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

When I input numbers on my 2 variables I think it doesn't read it, so `mov` has 0 value.

No problem compiling.

Here's my code:

```
include 'emu8086.inc'
org 100h

define_print_string
define_scan_num             
define_print_num            
define_print_num_uns
define_clear_screen

.model small
.data

;data
a db "oops",0
b db 0dh,0ah,"enter first number: ",0
c db 0dh,0ah,"the sum is :",0
d db 0dh,0ah,"Press 1 if adiition",0
e db 0dh,0ah,"Press 2 if subtraction",0
f db 0dh,0ah,"the diffirence is: ",0
g db 0dh,0ah,"enter second number: ",0
h db 0dh,0ah,"",0
num1 dw 0
num2 dw 0
result dw 0

;code
.code

start:
lea si,a
call print_string
lea si,d
call print_string
lea si,e
call print_string
mov ah,1
int 21h
cmp al,'1'
je addi
cmp al,'2'
je subt
cmp al,'?'
je start

;input number 1
proc enter1
lea si,b
call print_string
call scan_num
mov ax,num1
ret
endp enter1

;input number 2
proc enter2
lea si,g
call print_string
call scan_num
mov bx,num2
ret
endp enter2    

addi:
call enter1
call enter2
add ax,bx
lea si,h
call print_string
lea si,c
call print_string
call print_num

subt:

end1:

end
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El71n.png)

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Put four blanks in front of every line.

Comment: In your `enterX` procedure you set `ax` and `bx` from `num1` and `num2`. Variables that you initialized with zero and never written again. Read how [scan_num](https://github.com/AhmadNaserTurnkeySolutions/emu8086/blob/master/inc/emu8086.inc) works. Skipping the issues with formatting and not making a [mcve] the bigger problem you should handle *right now* is that your code is unreadable (bad formatting and the procedures are in the midst) and badly structured (`enter1` and `enter2` are the *same* procedure) If I were your teacher I would fail you immediately upon seeing it, to be sure, fix it.

Comment: Thanks,its just maybe our prof cant explain that macros(define) one and that ax,bx thing. My teacher thinks that we can make it,just because one of our classmate is advanced (who repeated 8086 subject) did it.I cant understand how his code works.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> call scan_num
> mov ax,num1
> ```

The *scan_num* macro leaves its result in the `AX` register. Therefore you need to store `AX` in the *num1* variable using `mov num1, ax`.
The same applies to entering the 2nd number.

---

> ```
> cmp al,'?'
> je start
> ;input number 1
> proc enter1
> ```

Consider what happens when the input is neither "1", nor "2", nor "?".
The code will fall through in the *enter1* procedure!
Better write:

```
jmp  start
;input number 1
proc enter1
```

---

You should calculate your sum as late as possible if you solely keep it in a register. You didn't use the *result* variable.

```
lea si,c
call print_string
mov  ax, num1
add  ax, num2
call print_num
```

Comment: Thank you Sir,i found a solution,the problem is at call scan_num and mov cx,num1

Comment: i just switched num1,cx

Comment: And yeah theres no need for the variable result,i can just call print_num below the message